# Restritction of permutation representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I was trying to do the following question on representations of $S_{n}$

> Consider the permutation representation of $S_{3}$ on $\mathbb{C}^3$. Suppose we restrict to each of the subgroups $H$ below. Describe explicitly how $\mathbb{C}^3$ decomposes as a direct sum of irreducible $H$-stable subspaces.
>
> a) $H$={(1),(123),(132)}
> b) $H$={(1),(12)}
> c) $H$={(1),(23)}

How does one approach such a question?

I know that restricting a representation to a subgroup does not change it's dimension. So the permutation representation restricted to the subgroup in $b)$ is still of dimension 3. But $H$ is of order 2 and is therefore abelian. So it can be decomposed into a sum of two one-dimensional subspaces. Isn't there a contradiction?
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: In b), it decomposes into three one-dimensional subspaces, spanned by $(1,1,0)$, $(1,-1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you please explain how you got those vectors?

Comment: It's really not difficult! You can do it by diagonalizing the matrix of the action of $(1,2)$.You should be able to do a) and c) yourself.